# Custom Authentication for different areas in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, authentication

I have a MVC project with 2 areas: Admin and Client. I also have a login page in the main controller. What I want to do is to Authenticate a user based on its roles. If the user is for client they can't login to admin and the other way around. 
For example if you try Localhost/admin, the code checks if the user is authorised. If not it redirects you to Localhost/admin/AccountLogin. The same for Localhost/client to Localhost/client/account/login.
I want to use a customAuthorize rather than [Authorize(Roles="Admin")].

everything works fine if I don't use roles, but the problem is if you login as client you can simply change the url and go to admin. So I tried to use roles.

In admin area:
An account Controller:
    public class AccountController : MainProject.Controllers.AccountController
    { }

A home controller:

```
[CustomAuthorize("Admin")]
public class HomeController : Controller
{

    public ActionResult HomePage()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

The custom Authorise:

```
public class CustomAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
    {
        private string _loginPage { get; set; }
        private string _customRole { get; set; }

        public CustomAuthorizeAttribute(string userProfilesRequired)
        {
            _customRole = userProfilesRequired;
            _loginPage = "/" + _customRole + "/Account/Login";
        }


        public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
        {
            var formsIdentity = filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity as System.Web.Security.FormsIdentity;

// I want to check if the role of current user is the same as the controller If not redirect to the /account/login page.

            var validRole = this.Roles == _customRole;//filterContext.HttpContext.User.IsInRole(_customRole);


            if (filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
               if (!validRole)
               {
                   filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Redirect(_loginPage);
               }
            }
            else
            {
                filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Redirect(_loginPage);
            }

            base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);


        }
    }
```

The Account Controller in Main Controller:

```
public class AccountController : Controller
{
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult Login()
    {
        return View();
    }

    //
    // POST: /Account/Login

    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model, string ReturnUrl)
    {
        try
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                if (model.UserName == "Arash" && model.Password == "123")
                {
                    FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.UserName, false);
                    //I need to set the roles here but not sure how
                    return RedirectToAction("homePage", "Home", new { area = GetArea() });

                }
            }

            ModelState.AddModelError("", "The user name or password provided is incorrect.");
            return View(model);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Error: " + ex.Message);
            return View(model);
        }
    }
```

}

and it the web config:

```
  <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login"  timeout="200"  />
</authentication>

<authorization>
  <allow roles="Admin,Client" />
</authorization>
```

I searched a lot in the web but couldn't find a proper answer. I appreciate if you Could help me out to correctly implement this authorisation in MVC.

I just want to know how can I set a role to a user when login. At the moment if I set a user in login, it can't remember when it gets to CustomAuthorize class.

Any help?
Cheers,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a lot of ways to this but I will tell you what I used in this case.

You don't actually need to create a custom Authorization Attribute but instead make use of `PostAuthenticateRequest` event Handler in `Global.asax` given that you have a "table" roles in your database.

Add the code below in `Global.asax`

```
public override void Init()
{
    this.PostAuthenticateRequest += new EventHandler(MvcApplication_PostAuthenticateRequest);
                        base.Init();
}

void MvcApplication_PostAuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated && User.Identity.AuthenticationType == "Forms")
    {
        string[] roles = GetRoleOfUser(Context.User.Identity.Name);
        var newUser = new GenericPrincipal(Context.User.Identity, roles);
        Context.User = Thread.CurrentPrincipal = newUser;

    }
}

public string[] GetRoleOfUser(string username)
{
    string[] usersInRole;
    // Get the Role of User from the Database
    // Should be of String Array
    // Example Query to Database: 'Select UserRole FROM User WHERE Username = "arash"'
    // It doesnt matter if user has One or more Role.

    return usersInRole;
}
```

Then your account controller should be this.

```
[HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model, string ReturnUrl)
    {
        try
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                if (model.UserName == "Arash" && model.Password == "123")
                {
                    FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.UserName, false);
                        HttpCookie authCookie = Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName];

                    return RedirectToAction("HomePage", "Home");

                }
            }

            ModelState.AddModelError("", "The user name or password provided is incorrect.");
            return View(model);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Error: " + ex.Message);
            return View(model);
        }
    }
```

Now for example there is an Action in your HomeController that can only be access by Admin. You can just decorate the action with `Authorize` attribute like this below.

`HomeController.cs`

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
public ActionResult AdminHomepage()
{
    //For Admin Only
    return View();
}

[Authorize(Roles = "Client")]
public ActionResult ClientHomepage()
{
    //Client only Homepage, User with Role "Admin" cant go here.
    return View();
}

[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult HomePageForAll()
{
    //For Everyone
    return View();
}

[Authorize(Roles = "Client,Admin")]
public ActionResult HomePageForClientAndAdmin()
{
    return View();
}

public ActionResult HomePage()
{
    return View();
}
```

The user will be redirected to Login URL if they are not authorized given that it is specified in Web.config (Which you already have set).

Comment: Thank you for your help. Very useful.

Comment: Glad I could help mate. :)

Answer (score 1):

I have an action method and that can be accessed by Admin only

```
    // Action Methods 
    [AuthorizationService]  // My custom filter ,you can apply at controller level
    public ActionResult ProjectList(Employee emp)
    {
      // do some work

    }
 //Employee class
   public class Employee
   {
      string Name{get;set;}
      string Role{get;set;}
  }
  // My custom filter 
   class AuthorizationService : ActionFilterAttribute
      {
         public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
         {
           Employee = filterContext.ActionParameters["emp"] as Employee;
           if (Employee.Role!="Admin")
           {
             filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(
                new RouteValueDictionary(
                 new { action = "Login", Controller ="Home"}));
           }

       }
   }
```